# 'Referred to as' or 'Referred as'?

Tags: prepositions

Which one is correct from the following sentences and why?

> This is **referred to as** enterprise mobility. 
>   This is **referred as** enterprise mobility.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

"Referred"  and "as" do not generally go together. Refer is usually used alone, where it means "directing someone's attention to something" or with "to", where it means "mentioned as". So the first sentence is right.